# Where to place my pictures from a harddrive

Tags: photos

So I've used windows all my life and am giving osx a shot.
I have an external harddrive full with images stored in multiple levels of directories.

eg.

```
 -car
    -ferrari 
    -audi
 -family
   -2020
 -house
```

Should I just copy everything to:

```
/users/myusername/Pictures
```

There is also a directory inside there called `Photos Library.photoslibrary` can that just be removed?

Comment: Why can't they just stay where they are, in the organizational system you're already using?

Comment: @MarcWilson The external drive is for backup. I dont want to connect my external drive every time I want to open a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Photos app, do not remove the Photo Photo Library.photolibrary directory.

You can place the pictures you have on your drive in the `Pictures` folder. What I would do is create a new folder inside Pictures and place my image files in there.

You can use the Photos app to browse your library in the directories you placed in the new folder under Pictures. If you would like to not use the Photos dedicated library, you can remove that option in the Preferences of Photos under General > Importing > Copy items to the Photos library. Make sure iCloud Photos is deselected under the iCloud tab in Photos.

Answer (score -1):

**You can make a folder that contains several sub-folders. And let's just call this folder `HDD-Photos`. So we create a folder within `~/Pictures`, otherwise everything is confusing.**

Use the terminal and use it to create a subdirectory of `~/Pictures`

```
mkdir ~/Pictures/HDD-Photos
```

Switch to the removable medium, the hard drive from which you want to transfer your data to the Mac afterwards.

```
cd /Volumes/HDD-Photos
```

Copy all files from the removable medium to the HDD-Photos folder

```
cp -R * ~/Pictures/HDD-Photos
```

***Note: If you don't want to work with the terminal, that's no problem either. You can import the photos/ videos from the removable medium into the folder of your choice in the Finder using drag & drop***

---

You can also import all of your photos & videos into the macOS photo library. To do this, simply open the directory with the ending ".photoslibrary" to open the Photos application. When you have this open you can press `SHIFT` + `CMD` + `I`. Now a Finder window opens where you can import your file.

Please note, however, that all of your videos and images are then stored in one directory. You can also select certain images from the photo library and save them in an album in the sidebar of the photo library. You can save multiple albums and store photos or videos on them.

If you prefer the variant above where everything is separated from each other, you can of course take the one above.

Comment: When you double click on .photolibrary you run Photos (the application). While drag&drop works well there, it comes with its own challenges which may need explaining.